# Making a Hive UDF persist across session?

Tags: hadoop, user-defined-functions, hive

How can I make a temporary function created with:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION function_name AS class_name
```

Persist in subsequent Hive sessions without having to recreate it each time? Is this possible or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best I've found is adding this code to .hiverc